# Windows 8 RT DateTime.FromOADate

Tags: date, datetime, windows-8, ole, windows-rt

Recently started porting an application from Windows Phone 8 to Windows 8 RT, and faced strange problem: can't find a way to convert DateTime structure to double OLE date.

Earlier, there were methods DateTime.FromOADate and DateTime.ToOADate to do this, but now they are not available.

```
...
double oaNow = System.DateTime.Now.ToOADate();  //ToOADate undefined
...
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason this was not included in the RT targets. It doesn't do anything particularly special, it it appears it could be portable.

You can probably duplicate the functionality in your own method by looking at the [Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1117) for the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks, shall do so. But really strange, that MS removed that methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
double oaNow = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1899, 12, 30)).TotalDays;
```

According to the documentation

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25; midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.25.